# Bootstrap nav-fixed-top overrides the text when page is reduced

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I known that are a lot of questions about this issue but I can´t get a satisfactory response yet.

I have a page with a menu build with the nav-fixed-top bootstrap class. The problem is that this menu overlaps the following content.

I some how resolve the problem defining a margin-top of 60px for the first element after the menu. The problem is when The page is reduced to the size of a mobile device the menu is expanded horizontally and again overlaps the following content.

My menu is created like this:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-static-top">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <a class=navbar-brand href="#">
           My Brand
         </a>
       </div>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li> 
      </ul>  
     </div>
   </nav>
```

And example of what is happening can be founded here: http://codepen.io/miguelbgouveia/pen/QEvyrR

What are the solution for this problem?

Comment: Pls take a look around this code. http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/dXWGQd

Comment: This is the way you expected have the menu. http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/EymKNo

Comment: That is a smart solution @Nehemiah but when the menu expand horizontally it not more is fixed in the top. If we scroll the page the menu disappear. See in this example: http://codepen.io/miguelbgouveia/pen/QEvyrR

Comment: It can be made fixed, but the problem appears in adding or removing any list in the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make media queries to set the margin-top for each device

[Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

Also don't use your title to set the margin-top (and certainly not an id). But make a extra class in your container like 'content' and set a margin for that. Or just use the body element.

```
/*standard value for mobile devices, bootstrap is mobile first: */
.content {
  margin-top:200px;
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
.content {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
 }


/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
 .content {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
}


/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
   .content {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
 }
```

Comment: I try your solution but it doesn't work. You can see id here: https://codepen.io/miguelbgouveia/pen/QEvyrR I am missing something?

Comment: The code i posted was with example values. I changed it to real values. you still need to mess around with the margin-top pixels to get the result that you need

Comment: i updated the code, i forgot to specify a standard value for the content (which is the mobile value, since bootstrap is mobile first). Try my new code, it should work

Comment: It works, I just need to define min-width: 768px with margin-top: 60px and max-width: 767px with margin-top: 200px.

Comment: We can see the working solution here: http://codepen.io/miguelbgouveia/pen/GqmkvV

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this code for a better standards. 
http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/dXWGQd

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a> </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4 id="first-title">Title 1</h4>
      <h4>Title 2</h4>
      <h4>Title 3</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's is a good solution but really don't like the collapse of the menu in an hamburger icon. See this article about the problems about hidden navigation: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/hamburger-menus/